# Lenovo Laptop cannot connect to the internet but is connected to the router

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, lenovo

Ive installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Laptop just yesterday and internet access seems to work pretty much never.
This laptop is also running Win10 which has no issues connecting at all.

Software is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Basically the main issue is, that it is able to connect to the router but still allows no external connections.
For exampe, pinging google.com just says something as unknown host or could not reach host.
I also cant ping my local gateway (192.168.2.1). Ive disabled ipv6 in every way possible, ipv4 is set on DHCP.
Now to the weird part; It might work just a couple minutes after a router restart sometimes but if i restart the pc in this period of time it stops working once again.
Router says that the PC is connected to the router.

Output of

```
cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
lsusb
iwconfig
rfkill list all
lsmod
```

is the following:

```
xaotic@memecat:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
Linux memecat 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
xaotic@memecat:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [17aa:381e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
xaotic@memecat:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:06b3 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 24db:3257  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
xaotic@memecat:~$ iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.


lo        no wireless extensions.


wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"WLAN-126827"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 84:9C:A6:D7:63:2D   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0


xaotic@memecat:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
xaotic@memecat:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
rfcomm                 69632  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
kvm                   536576  0
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
arc4                   16384  2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
aesni_intel           167936  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
rtl8821ae             225280  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
btusb                  45056  0
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
btintel                16384  1 btusb
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
serio_raw              16384  0
fam15h_power           16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
edac_core              53248  0
k10temp                16384  0
acpi_als               16384  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
ccp                    36864  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           57344  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
mac_hid                16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
amdkfd                131072  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1515520  3
psmouse               126976  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                    94208  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   360448  51 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
r8169                  81920  0
ahci                   36864  3
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
video                  40960  1 ideapad_laptop
fjes                   28672  0
```

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
xaotic@memecat:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:7b:9d:fe:6d:50  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:20778 (20.7 KB)  TX bytes:20778 (20.7 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:f7:72:33:2c:63  
          inet addr:192.168.2.107  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c7d:e090:bd1e:69e8/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2003:74:f6f:7dbe:c5a2:fa84:d379:7e87/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2003:74:f6f:7dbe:5c70:4b04:d868:dc97/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:194 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20101 (20.1 KB)  TX bytes:26815 (26.8 KB)
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(t) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

(no eth0 or wlan0 entry?)
And pinging:

```
xaotic@memecat:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks alot!

Comment: First of all, look if your PC has an IP address asigned (`ifconfig`) both when connection is working (if possible) and when it isn't working.

Comment: @migrc it does (wlp1s0: 192.168.2.107) but i cannot ping my gateway or any other local devices.

Comment: @migrc updated the thread and uploaded ifconfig (no eth0 or wlan0? Maybe renamed?)

Comment: You put a lot of stuff in your post, but can you also add output of `netstat -rn`

Comment: When testing your internet connection, I'd recommend to `ping 8.8.8.8` first, and then try `ping www.google.com`, that way you will be able to detect DNS problems if they exist.